# what is Single Frame Application and what is FrameView?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jdesktop

I have a basic understanding of Java Swing, I know about `JFrame` and `JPanel`. the problem is : Yesterday I started to write a `Simple Desktop Application in Netbeans`, I created a SingleFrameApplication, Netbeans created few classes for me one of them that contained main method was `public class ShamsApp extends SingleFrameApplication` and the other which was a view class `public class ShamsView extends FrameView`. Everything was fine until I tried to add a new JPanel to my application, at that point i found out that I can't add this `JPanel` to any of these classes, because none of them is a `JFrame` instance , so the questions raised, what are FrameView and SingleFrameApplication anyway? are they standard Swing JComponents? is it appropriate to ask questions like `JPanel Vs FrameView`? Or it is nonsense? Would you please enlighten me and future googlers?

Comment: `org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication` -> it's not standard swing but a jdesktop component.

Answer (score 4):

SingleFrameApplication is a part of the swing application framework, you can find all you want to know about it [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/swingappfr) if you want to play with the JFrames in FrameView, you can use the [getter](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/java/dev/appframework/appframework/1.03/appframework-1.03-javadoc.jar!/org/jdesktop/application/FrameView.html#getFrame%28%29) and [setter](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/java/dev/appframework/appframework/1.03/appframework-1.03-javadoc.jar!/org/jdesktop/application/FrameView.html#setFrame%28javax.swing.JFrame%29)